# How do I create a 3 column dataframe from 3 ListBuffers in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create a 3 column dataframe where each column is an existing ListBuffer

I have:

```
var list1= new ListBuffer[Int]()
var list2= new ListBuffer[String]()
var list3= new ListBuffer[String]()
```

Next I run some logic to append items to each of the lists, so let's assume they're populated and all of equal length.

Then I do:

```
var new_df = list1.toDF("list1_column")
```

and I was thinking I could just use withColumn to add the other 2 lists as additional columns, one by one. But it's saying:

"Type mismatch: expected Column. actual: ListBuffer[String]"

What should I do?

Thanks so much!

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Use `withColumn` & `typedLit` functions.

Try below code, If you have `DataFrame` object.

```
df
.withColumn("list1",typedLit(list1))
.withColumn("list2",typedLit(list2))
.withColumn("list3",typedLit(list3))
.show(false)
```

Try below code, If you don't have `DataFrame` object.

```
list1.toDF("list1")
.withColumn("list2",typedLit(list2))
.withColumn("list3",typedLit(list3))
.show(false)
```

Comment: this doesnt work. it doesnt add list2 and list3 as columns but rather as entire row values for each cell